# There cannot be a group of units of order $14$

Tags: group-theory, elementary-number-theory, proof-verification

I proved the following claim:

There is no $n$ such that $U(n)$ has order $14$.

> Please could someone tell me if my proof is correct?

$U(n)$ is the group of units modulo $n$ and $\varphi$ is the Euler function. The goal is to show that $\varphi (n)$ cannot equal $14$.

First, consider the case where $n = p^k$ ($n$ is a prime power). Then

$$ 14 = \varphi (p^k) = p^k - p^{k-1}$$

In order to show this is not possible I proved that if $p \ge q$ then for all $k\ge 0$:

$$ p^k - p^{k-1} \ge q^k - q^{k-1}$$

The proof is short so I will omit it here.

Using this result and the fact that

$$ \varphi(3^2) < 14 < \varphi (5^2)$$

and

$$ 14 < \varphi (3^3)$$

it follows that $14 \neq \varphi (p^k)$ for all $p$ and $k$.

Next consider the composite case, $14 = \varphi (st) = \varphi (s) \varphi (t)$. Since $14 = 2 \cdot 7$ this implies that $\varphi (s) = 2$ which implies $s=3$ and $\varphi (t) = 7$. But $\varphi (n)$ is never a prime hence this is not possible hence there is no group of units of order $14$.

Perhaps it is necessary to prove that $\varphi (n)$ cannot be prime.

> Is there a shorter proof than this?

Comment: $\varphi(3)=\varphi(4)=\varphi(6)=2$.

Comment: @AndréNicolas Ooops, right, I should write "primes greater than two". But is my proof otherwise correct?

Comment: The method will work. But you have not explained what you mean by the composite case, and you have not proved that $\varphi$ cannot be $7$. It is also not at all clear that the two "cases" you discussed cover all $n$.

Answer (score 2):

If $p\mid n$ then $p-1\mid \phi(n)$. Hence only primes $\in\{2,3,8,15\}$ are allowed, i.e., $n=2^a3^b$. But then $\phi(n)$ is also only divisible by primes $2$ and $3$, not $7$.

Comment: I'm sorry but please could you elaborate a little bit? We are given $\varphi (n) $ so how can we use $p \mid n \implies p-1 \mid \varphi (n)$ to deduce anything? We know $2$ and $7$ divide $\varphi (n)$ but that doesn't imply that $3$ and $8$ divide $n$. (?)

Comment: @astudent Assume $p\mid n$ for some prime $p$. Then $p-1\mid \phi(n)$, i.e., $p-1$ must be among the divisors $1,2,7,14$ of $\phi(n)$, i.e., $p$ must be among the numbers $2,3,8,15$. As $p$ is prime, only $p=2$ and/or $p=3$ are possible. - On the other hand, $q\mid \phi(n)$ for some odd prime $q$ implies that there is some $p$ with $p\mid n$ and either $p=q$ or $p\equiv 1\pmod q$; so $7\mid \phi(n)$ says that some prime $\ge 7$ divides $n$, which we just excluded.